Error instalar Spark windows 11
He instalado Spark ultima version al igual que Java, realizado todos los ajustes en windows 11 con winutils y variables de entorno, directorio tmp, etc ejecuto en el terminal(cmd), siguiendo todo el proceso segun el tutorial del que dispongo, voy a la terminal cmd del pc e intento arrancar pyspark y me salta el error de abajo segun intuyo tiene que ver con la SparkSession, SparkContext
Microsoft Windows [Versión 10.0.22631.4169]
(c) Microsoft Corporation. Todos los derechos reservados.
C:\Windows\System32>cd..

C:\Windows>cd..

C:\>cd spark

C:\spark>pyspark

Python 3.12.6 (tags/v3.12.6:a4a2d2b, Sep  6 2024, 20:11:23) [MSC v.1940 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
24/09/23 21:13:59 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes   where applicable
24/09/23 21:13:59 WARN SparkContext: Another SparkContext is being constructed (or threw an exception in its constructor). This     may indicate an error, since only one SparkContext should be running in this JVM (see SPARK-2243). The other SparkContext was   created at:

Hola Oscar, por favor edita la pregunta para añadir más detalles: ¿Cuando te sale este error? ¿Al ejecutar algún comando en concreto? ¿Al compilar algo? Lee [ask] y completa el [tour] para más información (y con ello ganarás tu primera medalla en el sitio)

He instalado una versión de Java inferior (la 21) y he conseguido instalar Spark después de bajar versión. Deduzco que ese era el problema.
